# Facing the issue : contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract

Tags: magento2, module

> Fatal error: Class Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute) in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News.php on line 11

Here's my code:

**/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News.php**

```
    <?php

     namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

     use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
     use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
     use Magento\Framework\Registry;
     use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
     use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

     class News extends Action
    {
     /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
   protected $_coreRegistry;

/**
 * Result page factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
protected $_resultPageFactory;

/**
 * News model factory
 *
 * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
 */
protected $_newsFactory;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param Registry $coreRegistry
 * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 * @param NewsFactory $newsFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    Registry $coreRegistry,
    PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
    NewsFactory $newsFactory
) {
   parent::__construct($context);
    $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
}

/**
 * News access rights checking
 *
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isAllowed()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news');
}



    public function execute()
 {
/** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

return $resultPage;
}
```

}

**/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News/Index.php**

```
   <?php

  namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

   use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News;

   class Index extends News
  {
/**
 * @return void
 */
   public function execute()
  {
  if ($this->getRequest()->getQuery('ajax')) {
        $this->_forward('grid');
        return;
    }

    /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setActiveMenu('Tutorial_SimpleNews::main_menu');
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Simple News'));

    return $resultPage;
```

}
}

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your file code with below one

**/home1/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Tutorial/SimpleNews/Controller/Adminhtml/News.php**

what your mistake is

> you are extending action class **Magento\Backend\App\Action** but you
>   have have to extend this  ***Magento\Backend\App\Action\Action*** class

```
 <?php

 namespace Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml;

 use \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\Registry;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
 use Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory;

 class News extends Action
{
 /**
 * Core registry
 *
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
      protected $_coreRegistry;


      protected $_resultPageFactory;

     /**
     * News model factory
       *
     * @var \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory
       */
     protected $_newsFactory;

 public function __construct(
Context $context,
Registry $coreRegistry,
PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
NewsFactory $newsFactory
  ) {
  parent::__construct($context);
      $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
   $this->_newsFactory = $newsFactory;
   }


 protected function _isAllowed()
     {
return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Tutorial_SimpleNews::manage_news');
      }



public function execute()
 {
   /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
     $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();

  return $resultPage;
}
```

Comment: now they showing this error

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory does not exist in [Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News\Index\Interceptor]

Comment: please clear your generated folder and clear cache and clean

Comment: php bin/magento cache:flush
Clear cache with this command and still facing issue

Comment: Have remove your generated folder?
rm -rf generated/* (if magento version >2.2.2) or rm -rf var/generation/*

Comment: Now another issue i faced
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement or after any declare call in the script

Comment: Remove the space after <?php and namespace

Comment: after removing namespace again 

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Class Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\NewsFactory does not exist in [Tutorial\SimpleNews\Controller\Adminhtml\News\Index\Interceptor]

Comment: Have remove your generated folder? rm -rf generated/* (if magento version >2.2.2) or rm -rf var/generation/*

Comment: still issue coming add your code in question  \Tutorial\SimpleNews\Model\News

Comment: yes still facing issue after remove your generated folder? rm -rf generated/*  commands